# How can I achieve this Database relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So a user can be a student or a parent. To define this relationship a User can be a parent but cannot be student, a parent many have many students.

This is the ERD for that relationship.

[image]

How would I create that relationship in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```
class User
  has_many :parents, through: 'students_parents'
  has_many :students, through: 'students_parents'

class StudentParent
  belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'User'
```